# React Native and Firebase: how to limit number of times data are fetched

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, use-effect

I'm currently working on an app with React Native using Firebase as backend. I won't be too specific on the details, but, basically, the app has to constantly fetch for new data uploaded, so I added this part in my main code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    db.ref('rooms').on('value', (data) => {
        if (startRoom.id) {
            ping = (data.val());
            setRoom(() => (data.val())[startRoom.id]);
        }
    }); 
},[ping]);
```

This way, every time new data are added in the object "rooms" in my db, the app is able to update all variables linked to it. This process however can cause some huge slowdowns and performance issues: indeed, when there are a lot of data uploaded by different users, or when data are uploaded very quickly (let's say, uploads are handled by user clicks, so very quick clicks can cause the db to go nuts), the app is constantly refreshing the page even several times per second, causing the slowdowns I was talking about.
So my idea is: is there anyway I can limit the number of fetches the firebase ref method does over time? Like, if the database is uploaded seven times in a second, it only catches the last one, ignoring the uploads which, for example, happened in a very short time. In other words I wonder if there is a way to limit the "sensitivity" of the ref method or the useEffect method of React Native.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If updates are happening multiple times a second, I think you should change your approach.

I think you should instead of updating your app with the data the moment it changes, store the changes in to an array `changes`, and set **one** interval that run for every, says 3 seconds, check the `changes` array. If there is data in it, use it to update your app and then clear the array. This way you can make sure your app only update at a fixed rate even if there is a lot of changes

Answer (score 0):

what's the data type of `ping`? If it's an object, your `useEffect` will run every time because of the way JavaScript checks for equality on objects (they check reference I believe).

A way around this is to use [useDeepCompareEffect](https://github.com/kentcdodds/use-deep-compare-effect) or lodash's [isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual). Or just use a primitive value as the dependency for your `useEffect`.